# Suppress Bluetooth discovery popup

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm building a bluetooth app for android. I have a UI button, and when I press it, I want to engage bluetooth discovery mode for 30 seconds. The code I have right now does this perfectly, however it generates a popup to ask if I want to allow bluetooth discovery. This popup kinda ruins the flow of my application, so is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't bypass it. The dynamic permissions were introduced with Android 6. This allows the user to specify the permissions he want to grant to an App more precisely.

For an Android user it doesn't ruin the flow. It is normal for him. This is how Android works (and iOS, too btw).

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

The `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`is considered as a normal permission. But for a scan, you also need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and/or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. These are classified as dangerous permissions and that's why you need to ask the user once.

also see: [BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback))

There are several blog posts on how to handle permissions. James Montemagno released a plugin for that.

- [Blog Post](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)
- [Permission Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)

Comment: is there an event that is raised when the user pressed okay on the the popup? If i knew when the prompt was over, it wouldn't break the flow so much

Comment: There are several blog posts on how to handle permissions. James Montemagno released a plugin for that. I updated my answer and added links

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check if it's enabled and enable it programmatically,

```
BluetoothManager btm = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bta = btm.getAdapter();
if (!bta.isEnabled()) {
  boolean ret = bta.enable();
  if (!ret) {
    // enable failed!
  }
}
```

You need to have the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: my problem isn't with enabling the adapter, its with starting discovery. I can enable the adapter just fine, but the discovery process still throws a popup. I edited the question to reflect this better